# How to update values in rows of a dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes one is bringing in values from the source file(XML) and the other is just the schema(XML File). My goal is to update the values in schemaDF with values from ValueDF.

I have created a dataframes like this

```
//XML Value Reader
    val supplyData="XMLData/SCI_Input.xml"
    val booksFileTag1 = "ROWSET"   

    val ValueDF = (new 
    XmlReader()).withRowTag(booksFileTag1).xmlFile(sqlContext, supplyData).toDF()
```

after reading the Values in ValueDF i have extracted out the specific fields from it like below

```
for (row <- ValueDF.rdd.collect)
    {

      var CLTCORP = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0)   
      var CTLITEM = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1)
      var CTLDIV = row.mkString(",").split(",")(2)
      var CTLFAC = row.mkString(",").split(",")(3)
      var CORP = row.mkString(",").split(",")(4)
      var DIVISION = row.mkString(",").split(",")(5)

      list.add(CLTCORP)
      list.add(CTLITEM)
      list.add(CTLDIV)
      list.add(CTLFAC)
      list.add(CORP)
      list.add(DIVISION)

}

    val CLTCORP = list.get(0)
    val CTLITEM = list.get(1)
    val CTLDIV = list.get(2)
    val CTLFAC = list.get(3)
    val CORP = list.get(4)
    val DIVISION = list.get(5)
```

Creating schemaDF

```
// XML Schema Reader

    val suppySchema="XMLData/SupplyChain.xml"
    val booksFileTag = "GetMaster"

    val schemaDF = (new XmlReader()).withRowTag(booksFileTag).xmlFile(sqlContext, suppySchema).toDF()

 //I am trying to update using the below code but i know it is not the correct way of doing it therefore seeking help to know how i can do it better

val test1df = schemaDF.withColumn("SupplyChain", when(col("SupplyChain.CorpId").isNull, CLTCORP).otherwise(CLTCORP))
```

The Output of my ValueDF is

```
+----------------------------+
|                         ROW|
+----------------------------+
|[1,1,1010008,17.0,DDPH,001] |
+----------------------------+
```

The output of my SchemaDF is

```
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
|        DocumentData|SupplyChain        |_noNamespaceSchemaLocation|                _xsi|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
|[[,2001-12-17T09:...|          [,,,,,]|      GetItemMasterSupp...  |http://www.w3.org...|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

The values i extracted from ValueDf i need to update in the SchemaDF and the expected output is like this

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+
|        DocumentData|SupplyChain                                   |_noNamespaceSchemaLocation |                _xsi|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|[[,2001-12-17T09:...|          [1,1,1010008,17.0,DDPH,001]         | GetItemMasterSupp...      |http://www.w3.org...|  
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+
```

Please help and suggest me to do this in best possible way.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have an element (like a key) which allows you to join the two dataframes?

Comment: Yes, I have appended incremental column like this val "dataFrame2 = schemaDf.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())" same way i appened column in ValueDF as well in same way. One more thing to mention columns like 'ROW', 'SupplyChain' are StructType